# Samsung Galaxy S5 Active no SIM Card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, unbricking, sim-card, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I tried rooting my device with towelroot only to find out it didn't work. I went to bed before doing this, and when I woke up my phone said no SIM card, please insert in the notification bar. I got rootchecker from the playstore and it said my device wasn't rooted. I tried removing the SIM card, and then re-inserting it, which didn't seem to work. I then tried to factory restore my phone. It still didn't seem to work, so then I googled the problem. I checked my "about device" and everything seems ok. I then went to status and it seemed alright, I had IMEI number is there, but my mobile network type is unknown so is my service state, mobile network state, phone number. I have no idea how to fix it, so I thought I would make a thread of my own before I go into AT&T and try to talk to them about it. I can't call, access my mobile data, or text. Basically just an iPod with wifi.

Model Number : SAMSUNG-SM-G870A
Android Version 4.4.2

Comment: Just download the original firmware for your device and flash it.
Everything should be back to normal.

Answer (score -3):

You have destroyed your gadgets mother board while trying to root your device with towelroot. Now the only solution is that you have to change the mother board
of your device.

Comment: This sounds like nonsense.  How exactly does towelroot affect the board?

Comment: And how did you reach this conclusion? How about citing some sources?